# Was ist das Unterscheid zwischen "mit dem Zug" und "beim Zug"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Original Fassung:

> Heute fährt er mit dem Zug nach Paris.

Gibt es einen Unterschied, wenn ich sagen würde?

> Heute fährt er beim Zug nach Paris.

Comment: Warum um alles in der Welt sollte man "beim Zug fahren" sagen statt "mit dem Zug fahren"? - Die einzige Antwort, die mir einfällt ist, dass da jemand meint, er könne Englisch Wort für Wort übersetzen: *I go by train.* - *Ich gehe bei Zug.* Oh je, oh je!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich höre zufälligen deutschen Programmen wie Deutche Welle(http://www.dw.com) zu, während ich  laufe und jemand etwas wie "fährt beim Zug oder beim Auto" gesagt hat, aber manchmal bin ich irreredend, während ich laufe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seemingly based on a mis-understanding. There's no way to say "Ich fahre bei Zug" in German

Comment: @tofro maybe I should just delete it and upvote 5 of korinnas questions to be nice? :)

Comment: Don't really dig the close votes. The question is perfectly answerable, albeit close to a "general reference" q: The difference between the two examples is one is correct and the other isn't.

Comment: "Beim Zug fahren" would mean that someone is driving something **near** the train. For example you are are in the railway station where you are driving your bicycle. Of course you could drive your bicycle on the platform near the train...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Diese Version ist nicht richtig:

> Heute fährt er beim Zug nach Paris.

Man fährt mit dem Zug.

Beim ist eine Zusammenfassung von bei und dem.

Quasi: Bei dem Zug fahren
anstatt mit dem Zug fahren.

Dann ist die Präposition falsch.